# Error: C stack usage 15925344 is too close to the limit when running plot a sampling in R

Tags: r

I run a simple samling code in r, and got a error : **Error: C stack usage  15925344 is too close to the limit**
I try several methods on line to fix it, but fail. I think it is a simple fix, but do not know how. Any help will be appreciated.

```
set.seed(1)

sam<-rnorm(1000,m,s)

mean(sam)

summary(replicate(100,mean(rnorm(1000,m,s))))

cumean<-function(x) cumean(x) / seq_along(x)

plot(cumean(sam), type="l", xlab="Sample", ylab="Cumulative mean",
     panel.first=abline(h=0, col="red"), las=1,axes = F)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `cumean()` in the definition of `cumean()`.

You'll want to use `cumsum()` instead:

```
set.seed(1)

sam<-rnorm(1000)

mean(sam)

summary(replicate(100,mean(rnorm(1000))))

cumean<-function(x) cumsum(x) / seq_along(x)

plot(cumean(sam), type="l", xlab="Sample", ylab="Cumulative mean",
     panel.first=abline(h=0, col="red"), las=1,axes = F)
```

Notice that I eliminated references to `m` and `s` since we don't have access to those values (see [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)); this means the code above is just using the defaults of 0 and 1 respectively.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is my simple mistake.

Comment: @Grace no worries! In my experience, it's much easier to spot simple things like this in other people's code than your own